# Adventureworks MDX select data between dates

Tags: mdx, adventureworks

I'm currently working with the MDX queries and the Adventure Works database.
What i'm trying to achieve is to get all the data per quarter between 2 quarters.

For example all the data between 2006 Quarter 2 & 2009 Quarter 3 divided over the quarters.

The closest i've come to achieving what I want is using the following query:

```
SELECT { KPIValue("Channel Revenue"), KPIStatus("Channel Revenue") } ON Columns,
    {( 
        {[Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2006]:[Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2009]},
        {[Fiscal Quarter of Year].&[FY Q1]:[Fiscal Quarter of Year].&[FY Q4]}
    )} ON Rows
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

I've combined a range from 2006 - 2009 with a range of Quarter 1 - Quarter 4.

Below you see the result of my query on the left and on the right the result that I want.

[image: Data]

I tried to use the query above with Quarter 2 & Quarter 3 as you can see below, but that query only returns the data from quarter 2 & 3 per year.

```
{[Fiscal Quarter of Year].&[FY Q2]:[Fiscal Quarter of Year].&[FY Q3]}
```

I have also tried the following query:

```
SELECT
    { KPIValue("Channel Revenue"), KPIStatus("Channel Revenue") } ON Columns,
    {( [Date].[Date].&[20060401]:[Date].[Date].&[20090901] )} ON Rows
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Using this query I get the data I want from the period of time that I want, but it is per day and not per quarter.

## Question

How do I get the data per quarter for the quarters between the 2 given quarters

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this problem. By using the following query it is possible to achieve what I wanted:

```
SELECT
    { KPIValue("Channel Revenue"), KPIStatus("Channel Revenue") } ON Columns,
    {( [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter].&[2006]&[2] : [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter].&[2009]&[3])} ON Rows
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

So by changing *Fiscal Quarter of Year* to *Fiscal Quarter* and by selecting the year and quarter using

```
 .&[2006]&[2]
```

its possible to select the quarter of a certain year.
And by using 2 of this quarters and a range its possible to get all the data between those 2 quarters.

```
[Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter].&[2006]&[2] : [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter].&[2009]&[3]
```